# How can I recover tethering conection after ubuntu-drivers autoinstall in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, 20.04, tethering

I'll try to make the story short.
My Blender was crashing my entire system when I was trying to manipulate materiales and I read the solution was to make a driver upgrade so I performed

> sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

And rebooted.
The good news are Blender is working perfectly now.
The bad news are I'm now unable to usb tethering conect and I can't access the Internet.
The computer still reconize my HUAWEI P30 and ask me what I want to do (tranfer photos, files or just charge) and I can activate the usb tethering on settings in my Phone. It even looks like it is connected from my Phone, but no signals of conection on the computer, which is offline.

Can someone please help me to understand and overtake this issue?
Really appreciated.

Felipe

Comment: It may have just forgotten your computer. The internet tethering is controlled on your HUAWEI P30 not on the computer. Do you get a different result if you connect the HUAWEI P30 while the computer is off. Unlock your screen, then power on the computer and log in? Does the HUAWEI P30 then prompt you to "allow" connection?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. In fact the phone prompt me but not to allow connection. It ask me if I want to 1)Transfer photos. 2)Transfer files. 3)Only charge, plus the option to cancel. Note that if, for example I choose Transfer Files, I'm able to transfer files until I activate the option USB Tethering on the phone settings, then I lost the connection to transfer until I disable tethering again. What else could I try?